# Maintaining active tab in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on an application that has three tabs, one of which I would like to have marked as active at all times. Based on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044370/make-clicked-tab-active-in-bootstrap), I currently have the following in my base template:

```
<div class="tab">
    <a class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'home' %}active{% endif %}" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'questions' %}active{% endif %}" href="/questionManager/">Question Manger</a>
    <a class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'course' %}active{% endif %}" href="/courseManager/">Course Manager</a>
</div>
```

Which works great when navigating between `/`, `/questionManager/`, and `/courseManager/`, respectively. The issue is that if I navigate to another page (for example, `/questionManager/addQuestion/`), the tab is no longer marked as active. Is there a way that I can maintain the active state no matter where I want to navigate? Specifically, the 'question' tab should be marked active for all `/questionManager/*`, the 'course' tab should be marked active for all `/courseManager/*`, and the 'home' tab should be marked active for everything else. I realize I could pass along some variable indicating whether it's question/course/home in the context whenever I'm rendering a response, but that seems like a lot of repetition and I feel like there's an easier way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the template tag `in` operator AND changing the format of 'home' etc to '/home/' as well as checking if each string is in the request.path as that provides each relative url in the format '/questions/1'.

```
<div class="tab">
    <a class="{% if '/home/' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="{% if '/questions/' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" href="/questionManager/">Question Manger</a>
    <a class="{% if '/course/' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" href="/courseManager/">Course Manager</a>
</div>
```

[Django Template Tags In Operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference...I think it's probably because 'questions' is not in the URL, it is just the name given in urls.py. I tried doing `{% if 'questionManager' in request.resolver_match.url_name %}` to see if that might match with the URL but it actually made it worse (my question tab never gets marked active).

Comment: See if my edit works. Try checking if the string (which should include the slashes) is in request.path instead of request.resolver_match.url_name.